# Changing ID in one place changes ID in other places in Android XML file

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

This issue started happening when I copied a layout into another and tried to refactor the ID in the new file. It tends to refactor the ID in the source file also.
This is quite frustrating as the layout I've designed for a particular activity gets change everytime I try to update several IDs of its views.

I'm a super beginner in Android Studio and any kinda help/guidance would be really appreciated! Thanks!!

Comment: What your exact issue can you please tell us with some code. Like I'm not getting it if you refactor using ide will reflect all the id in your project. If you want to change the copied xml widget Id then go to the file and change it instead of using refactor.

Comment: This is the android expected behavior as other elements might be constrained to the element whose I'd is getting changed.

Comment: Refactor means to update. So while copying a layout into another, when I updated the IDs of its TextViews, it modified the IDs into the source layout also. And nevermind! It took me a minute to realise that I need to update the IDs in the new file through its text editor AND NOT from the design section. Working fine now :DDD

Comment: This is how the refractor is supposed to work as far as of my knowledge.

Comment: Yeah, I'm a super beginner anyway :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

every time you refactor something, it will change everything related to that particular item or field, if you want to refactor an ID of an item it will change it in everywhere this ID is being used.
in order to change the name you can right click and choose refactor and rename or you can press SHIFT+F6 for a shortcut, it will ask you if you want t search it in comments and strings also check that box in order to really change it everywhere that this item is being used.

If you want to rename only the ID in the xml without it being changed in the java file, you'll have to change it by hand 1 by 1 b/c the refactor option will change it everywhere it is being used in your current project.