# Android Studio - prevent changing ids in all XML files

Tags: android, android-studio

I think it only began since latest update:

I copied a vie layout and renamed it.

Then I changed the id of a TextView inside the new view layout from `commentText` to `replyText`.

POStudio asked then if I want to change all usages of commentText as well, I have choosen `No (local only)` (the other options are preview, cancel and yes) but POStudio still changes the ids in both layouts. How can I make this software stop doing it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android Studio changing ID's in one xml file changes the ID's in another file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50660446/android-studio-changing-ids-in-one-xml-file-changes-the-ids-in-another-file)

Comment: When two views have the same ID across multiple files, the integer ID generated is the same for both so it's effectively the same ID. So they all get renamed because that's the expected behavior in some way. Could Android Studio be smarter? Yes, but that's not currently the case. My suggestion is either to use unique IDs for each layout, or refactor manually.

Comment: "use unique IDs for each layout" This is what I'm trying to do by changing them in one file, or what exactly do you mean? I don't understand why there is the option (no locally only) when studio changes the ids everywhere anyway instead of only in the damn file where you try to change the id

Comment: If you want to change only in one file, just use search and replace (Ctrl+R). By unique IDs per layout I mean `fragment1.xml` will have `@+id/fragment1_btn` and `fragment2.xml` will have `@+id/fragment2_btn` instead of just `@+id/btn` for both. What you want isn't really possible to implement. How would Android Studio know which `R.id` constant to rename when they can be found everywhere, not tied to a specific XML layout? It is simply impossible.

Comment: Ok makes sense thanks